# RestSharp issues integrating with zscaler product will not work on IIS Server 2012 R2

Tags: vb.net, iis, restsharp, windows-server-2012-r2, zscaler

Our organization is removing our proxy web servers and integrating Zscalar.  We were informed that all we had to do is remove the proxy property/settings.  So I have removed the proxy setting from my code and it seems to work fine locally but it will not work on our server.  Is there something I am missing here?  We are also using RestSharp 105.2.30

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim utils As New Utilities.Common
Dim rc As RestSharp.RestClient
rc = New RestSharp.RestClient("https://www.someendpointurl")
Dim rr As New RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST)
rr.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & RetrieveTokens("MSIC"))
Dim rs As New RestSharp.RestResponse()
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
rs = rc.Execute(rr)
dctValues = js.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(rs.Content)
```

Comment: For anyone to answer, you will most likely need to expand on "will not work".   I would also suggest you might tag in IIS (or what ever you hosting server is).  Working properly locally suggest to me it's a server config/environment issue of some nature

Comment: `it will not work on our server.` You need to share some error message or any other things to let us know what you mean it not work.

Comment: Problem has been resolved.  So it turns out that there was a rule blocking access to the End Point URL.  The code above works fine.  Thanks everyone for your help and input.   Also the only error I was getting from RestSharp was Code status=0 Object not being set.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trouble-shooting, turns out in this case it was not a code issue.  It was a internet and firewall connection issue on the server.  So the code above is valid and works grea